# Excel 2013 added quotes in Indirect or Concatenate functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using a nested If formula in a table.  I want to copy the formula across many columns, with some references changes and other remaining static.  Using table references, i.e., [Hourly Rate], I'm not able to create an absolute reference, i.e., `$A$1:$A$5000` which is not a viable option.

My attempted solution was to use an indirect reference:

```
=INDIRECT("["&$A$1&"]")
```

I expected it to calculate to `INDIRECT([Hourly Rate])`, but instead it gives me `INDIRECT("[Hourly Rate]")`, and results in `#REF`.

There's obviously more to the equation, but that is where it errors out.

Why am I getting extra quotation marks?

Working formula, but I cannot copy to other columns:

Answer (score 0):

It's an all too common myth that absolute and relative references do not both exist in a table.

Absolute
`=TableName[[ColumnName]:[ColumnName]]`

Relative
`=TableName[ColumnName]` or `=TableName[@[ColumnName]]` or  `=[@[ColumnName]]`

The difference is small but significant. Absolute references are enclosed by an additional set of brackets `[ ]`

Comment: **Relative**: `=TableName[ColumnName]`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld /Facepalm thank you